# Flutter PIN Verification Countdown

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I made a pin verification with countdown using the timer_count_down package. What I'm trying to do is when the countdown is finished, it shows a text saying "Resend PIN" to resend the PIN to email and starts the countdown again.

Here is my Login.dart code snippet when I enter my email address it sends a PIN code to my email :

```
...
Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: TextFormField(
              cursorColor: Color(0xFF2481CF),
              autofocus: true,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !EmailValidator.validate(value.trim())) {
                  return 'Email is not valid!';
                }
                return null;
              },
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF2481CF)),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF2481CF)),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Enter your email :',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                  )
                ),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 19.0,
                height: 1.3,
              ),
            ),
          ),
...

floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      // onPressed: _submit,
      onPressed: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          showDialog<String>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Text('PIN code will be sent to'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text(_controller.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  Text('Is this OK or would you like to edit the email address?'),
                ],
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, 'Cancel'),
                  child: const Text('Edit',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                    ),),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //kirim email

                    sendEmail(_controller.text.trim());

                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  PinVerification(_controller.text.trim())),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Verify',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF2481CF)
                    ),),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        };
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.send),
    ),
```

And for the PinVerification.dart :

```
Widget onlySelectedBorderPinPut() {
    final BoxDecoration pinPutDecoration = BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(235, 236, 237, 1),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    );
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Text(
            'Enter 6 digit code we sent to your email.',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () {
              print(_formKey.currentState?.validate());
            },
            child: PinPut(
              validator: (s) {
                if (s != null && s.contains('1')) return null;
                return 'NOT VALID';
              },
              useNativeKeyboard: true,
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
              withCursor: true,
              fieldsCount: 6,
              fieldsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.black),
              eachFieldMargin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
              eachFieldWidth: 45.0,
              eachFieldHeight: 55.0,
              onSubmit: (String pin) => postRequest(pin),
              focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
              controller: _pinPutController,
              submittedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
              selectedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 2,
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(160, 215, 220, 1),
                ),
              ),
              followingFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
              pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.scale,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Countdown(
            seconds: 20,
            build: (_, double time) => 
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Send PIN again in ',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle?.color
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: time.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF2481CF),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      )),
                      TextSpan(text: ' sec',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.labelStyle?.color
                      ))
                    ]
                  ),
                ),
            onFinished: () {

            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the screenshot for my PinVerification.dart:

[image]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Created custom timer It worked for me

```
 late Timer _timer;
 int _start = 60;


 void startTimer() {
const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
_timer = new Timer.periodic(
  oneSec,
  (Timer timer) {
    if (_start == 0) {
      setState(() {
        timer.cancel();
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _start--;
      });
    }
  },
);
}

    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  
    startTimer();
  
  }

    @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _timer.cancel();
    errorController!.close();
  }
```

And inside widget check condition as follows:

```
 _start != 0
              ? Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Resend Code in",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      _start.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: MyTheme.yellow,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : YourWidget() // your widget here
```

When the Resend Otp is clikced reset the timer is as follows:

```
setState(() {
                                _start = 60;
                                startTimer();
                              });
```

Comment: where do you define the errorController?